# EC2 Instance is only listening to Port 22

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, ssh, npm

I am trying to deploy a node app into AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance, but I am getting issues. It seems like for some reason it is only listening to port 22 (the default portal for SSH), and not my HTTP port.

[netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaE7S.png)

[AWS Security Group Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gaavf.png)

As you can see in the link above, I did manually include port 80 as well as others into my security group. I don't think this is a firewall issue from what I have read.

My Express server code:

```
const express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  cookieSession = require('cookie-session'),
  port = 8000,
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  mongoDB = require('./keys.js').database,
  passport = require('passport'),
  passportSetup = require('./passportConfig'),
  keys = require('./keys'),
  bluebird = require('bluebird');

mongoose.Promise = bluebird;
app.listen(port, () => {
  mongoose.connect(mongoDB)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('successfully connected to MongoDB. Listening to 
port ', port);
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('error connecting to MongoDB.');
  });
});
```

I am able to actually access my Node server, but connection is refused in the browser.

[NPM Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jg90.png)

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Just for debugging purposes, it's probably worth getting rid of process.env.PORT and just leaving the `8000` setting so we can be sure that this isn't the problem. Could you check that and then update your question?

Comment: Sure. I did get the same result after modifying that code.

Comment: Cool thanks, can you also provide your stdout and stderr for the application? Sorry, I'm struggling to see what's wrong so more info would be great!